# VBA Code: How would you split a string in a cell into sections and displaying those section in a new column using offset function

Tags: excel, vba

- I am trying to find a way that takes a player's name from cell A2 which in that cell reads (Name, Position, School) and splitting their name, position, and school in a different columns using the offset command. The problem I am having is when I split the cell it also splits the name and I need the name to stay together. For example, Jaylen Coleman RB Duke It splits it into "Jaylen" "Coleman" "RB" "Duke" when I need it to split into "Jaylen Coleman" "RB" "Duke" and then offset those splits 12 columns over.

```
Sub ParseName()
    Dim ACC As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim PlayerPosition As Range
    Dim dataList As Range
    Dim arrData As Variant
    Dim i As Variant

    Set ACC = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ACC Statistics")
    lastRow = ACC.Cells(ACC.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set dataList = ACC.Range("A1").Resize(lastRow, 1)

    For Each PlayerPosition In dataList
        arrData = Split(PlayerPosition.Value)
        For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
            ACC.Cells(PlayerPosition.Row, i + 12).Value = arrData(i)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you guarantee that the position and school are always one word each?

Comment: Can you guarantee that the name has always exactly two words?

Comment: If you have predefined set of positions you can use regex to split and capture all 3

Comment: You need to know if there are lines like `Jaylen X. Coleman RB Duke` or `Jaylen Coleman RB Wild West School of Arts` - or both. With other words: You need to find a way to tell which word belongs to what.

Comment: @FunThomas, what.... Wild West School of Arts has an (American) football team?

Comment: No, the range cell reads Jaylon Coleman RB Duke. There are only spaces in between each area

Comment: I have not the slightest idea, neither about schools in the US nor about football...

Comment: The name could either be Jaylon Coleman or Thad Franklin Jr. so either two or three words per name. The Position is always two letters like RB, QB, WR. The school will always be the last word of the cell like GATECH, MIAMI, WAKE.

Comment: @FunThomas - yeah I know, I was going along with your joke. Great name for a school btw.

Answer (score 0):

Try this I've added random positions RR and ZZ, just use | as an "or"

```
Sub rege()
    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Pattern = "(.+) (RB|RR|ZZ) (.+)"
        With .Execute("Jaylen X. Coleman RB Duke")
            If .Count > 0 Then
                If .Item(0).Submatches.Count = 3 Then
                    MsgBox .Item(0).Submatches(0) & vblf & _ 
                           .Item(0).Submatches(1) & vblf & _
                           .Item(0).Submatches(2)
                End If
            End If
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Your code should look like this (If you are not a mac user :)

```
Sub ParseName()
    Dim ACC As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim PlayerPosition As Range
    Dim dataList As Range
    Dim arrData As Variant
    Dim i As Variant

    Set ACC = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ACC Statistics")
    lastRow = ACC.Cells(ACC.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set dataList = ACC.Range("A1").Resize(lastRow, 1)

    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Pattern = "(.*) (RB|QB|WR) (.*)"
        For Each PlayerPosition In dataList
            With .Execute(" " & PlayerPosition.Value & " ")
                If .Count > 0 Then
                    If .Item(0).Submatches.Count > 0 Then
                        For i = 0 To .Item(0).Submatches.Count - 1
                            ACC.Cells(PlayerPosition.Row, i + 12).Value = Trim(.Item(0).Submatches(i))
                        Next i
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Add all your positions in Pattern string in `RB|QB|WR` part just use `|` as a separator